# Wait for XHR request to return 200 and loop

Tags: javascript, loops, xmlhttprequest, chat

this is my first post here. I've been writing a chat script for a while now, but I've come across an issue. When I use my original code, the browser freezes because it's still trying to load. I have tried almost everything. I'm a bit stumped because I had an idea to clone the function to go back and forth and it STILL won't work. Here is a snippet of what I'm working with.

```
function jumpanti(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, SeaMonkey
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                
     
   
            
                document.getElementById("chatContent").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                antifreeze();
                
                
        
                
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "innerchat.php", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        twemoji.parse(document.body);
        // Twemoji parse
        
        
}



function antifreeze(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, SeaMonkey
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                
     
   
            
                document.getElementById("chatContent").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                jumpanti();
                
                
        
                
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "innerchat.php", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        twemoji.parse(document.body);
        // Twemoji parse
        
        
}
```

I've tried and it still won't work. What I want my code to do is to try and load the chat until it gets a 200 response and then loop. Does anyone have any solutions to this using only XHR?

Comment: It's more common to write chat apps with web sockets than with xhr.  Check out https://medium.com/@noufel.gouirhate/build-a-simple-chat-app-with-node-js-and-socket-io-ea716c093088  Also, do you really need to support IE5 and IE6?  I bet you don't. :)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem. The issue was I didn't have asynchronous XML turned on inside the function. It froze the page a lot. I changed `xmlhttp.open("GET", "innerchat.php", false);` to `xmlhttp.open("GET", "innerchat.php", true);`